# use translate method with one parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to use translate method with one parameter 
I know that it takes a table and deletechars but I only want to use the deletechars one ... 
this my code

```
import os


def re_name():
    pic_dir = r"C:\Users\Maysara\Desktop\aaa"
    file_list = os.listdir(pic_dir)
    os.chdir(pic_dir)
    for item in file_list :
         new_name = item.translate(None,"1234567890")
         os.rename(item,new_name)
    print("done")

re_name()
```

I have this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Maysara/PycharmProjects/untitled1/hello.py", line 14, in 
>       re_name()
>     File "C:/Users/Maysara/PycharmProjects/untitled1/hello.py", line 10, in re_name
>       new_name = item.translate(None,"1234567890")
>   TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Comment: Sounds like you're using Python 3.x - is that correct?

Comment: yep ... that's true

Comment: It only takes the translation table as input `S.translate(table) -> str`

Comment: Having a look for another dupe but you're basically after `new_name = item.translate({ord(ch): None for ch in '0123456789'})` or `.translate(str.maketrans('', '', '0123456789'))`